# While polling Server, how to update the content of a lightbox... using Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, lightbox, colorbox

While watching railscasts #229 Polling for Changes, I'm trying to achieve kind the same result, except that I want the content of a lightbox to dynamically be changed until user closes it.

I have an index action, that will iterate elements, and for every element, I'll put a link what will open the lightbox and then it will automatically poll the server, and update content within the lightbox (I'm using Colorbox)

So, in index action:

```
- @systems.each do |system|
    =link_to "Get Uname", get_uname_system_path(system), :remote => true
```

Then in the get_uname action, I will call js.erb

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js #get_uname.js.erb
end
```

And finally in the get_uname.js.erb file, I open the lightbox:

```
 $.colorbox({html: "<div id=\"ajax-content\"></div>", innerWidth:425, innerHeight:344});
```

Until now, The lightbox open successfully, but I don't know to update the content of it, every 1 sec...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using polling might be good for you but to me the best practice for this is [faye](http://rubygems.org/gems/faye) gem. you are a railscast fan so u would not have problem setting this up.. with this your light box would be updated instantly.

Comment: Thanks... it took a little while... but now I can update lightbox through FAYE